# Using FactoryGirl in Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've been having trouble accessing my FactoryGirl definitions within the rails console of the spec/dummy scope. I understand that as my definitions are in the spec/factories folder they would not be accessible to the console, but how would I go about including or finding these definitions for in it.

The namespace of FactoryGirl is defined within both the test and development console environment, however the factories I have in factories.rb in spec/factories are not registered.

My setup is from this tutorial: http://viget.com/extend/rails-engine-testing-with-rspec-capybara-and-factorygirl

Comment: Can you please provide some configuration code and the piece of code which is causing the issue. It will be better for someone to answer your questions if you could provide code snippets and what you think might be the reason for error.

Comment: @harshs08 The exact code within that link is the offender. That is the barebones application config. Perhaps I should reword the question so that it is less contextually code based and more of a request for a how-to. I just need to know how to access the Factories within the console of an engine, but because the console is ran from spec/dummy the definitions within spec/factories are not accessed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 Use Factory Girl factories from Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342466/rails-4-use-factory-girl-factories-from-engine)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261585/how-to-use-factorygirl-factories-from-an-engine

Comment: @BradWerth Not exactly, I would like to be able to use my factories within rails console independently of any other app.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an error like this for the longest time, no matter what stackoverflow suggestion I tried:

```
ArgumentError: Factory not registered: item
```

I finally realized that when my factories were generated, my engine's name was being prefixed in the factory file, so that instead of:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :item do
    ...
  end
end
```

I was seeing:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_engine_item, :class => 'MyEngine::Item' do
    ...
  end
end
```

In the end to get things to work I simply referred to `my_engine_item` instead of `item` in my `FactoryGirl` declarations, so that:

```
FactoryGirl.build(:item)
```

becomes

```
FactoryGirl.build(:my_engine_item)
```

It's not a very elegant solution and maybe not even the solution to your problem, but I thought I would share what I went through for whatever it's worth.